# Booking domestic flights in Iran

Tags: air-travel, iran

Is there any way to book domestic flights in Iran from abroad, or does it need to be done in the country? Are the ticket prices fixed? And how long in advance should I book the flights to make sure there are places available?

I am so used to booking in the Internet and pay with my credit card :)

Answer (score 5):

It is near impossible to book domestic flights of Iran from abroad because they usually do not accept any foreign credit card. If you have a local bank account, you can book a ticket online. 
You may check out these websites too.

https://www.uppersia.com/Iran-travel-QA/domestic-flight-reservation.html

http://www.aitotours.com/flights/

Answer (score 3):

Considering the banking ban is effectively still in place, it is not possible to use a credit card outside Iran to pay for something inside Iran. So, a conventional booking would not be possible, though a reservation would be, in theory.

Edit with some clarification: The banking ban was American and penalised (pretty much) any company doing business with Iran as well as the US. So, anyone selling airline tickets and doing business with Iran could therefore not do business with, or in, the US. As the American market is somewhat larger than the Iranian market, the choice is easily made.

Note that this ban, in this form, is no longer in place. But, as I pointed out at the top, international bank transfers and payments to and from Iran, are currently not yet available.

Comment: And in practice?

Comment: I don't see why the credit card issue would prevent foreign travel agencies to sell Iranian domestic airline tickets?

Comment: Wouldn't that depend on exactly where *abroad* is?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo How would the travel agency pay the airline? The travel agency would have the same problem paying as anyone else.

Comment: @dirkk The reason why credit cards do not work in Iran is a US ban on conducting financial services with/in Iran and that most credit cards are offered by US based companies. Transferring money from other countries to Iran, e.g. with an international wire transfer, is usually not a problem.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Under US pressure, IATA was forced to suspend the membership of Iranian carriers from its Billing and Settlements Plan. That means a travel agent needs to find an alternative way to handle electronic financial transactions with Iranian carriers. Any kind of interlining will be a nightmare. Further, if the travel agent or airline prefers to use electronic tickets, the software will have to be rewritten to accommodate the alternative transaction flow. For most travel agents, this is simply not worth it.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I found https://www.tcharter.ir/en#!all very useful, as it has an English menu and has the cheapest prices for domestic flights.